# Error using visual studio2015 for remote debugging on ios (lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd)

Tags: ios, cordova, osx-yosemite, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

When we first time start the remote agent for visual studio ios debugging, it installs Homebrew and its packages ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn757054%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ios)). While doing so, I am getting following error:

```
Error installing homebrew packages:
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c (brew list ideviceinstaller | grep ideviceinstaller > /dev/null || brew install ideviceinstaller) &&                                                             (brew list ios-webkit-debug-proxy | grep ios-webkit-debug-proxy > /dev/null || brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy)

 Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ideviceinstaller
 Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool     installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.
Warning: This keg was marked linked already, continuing anyway
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd
 Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
 Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _map_fd
 Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
 Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Error: Failed to fix install names
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Please help me with the issue

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, the install_name_tool needs to be restored to a version that is known/expected. If you have another OS X installation, you can get the version of the file from there. Alternatively, this file also exists under Xcode:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool
```

Maybe restoring it from there will work? I haven't tried that before, so it may be a bit risky :P

Cheers,

Kirupa

Comment: which install_name_tools needs to be replaced with the one you mentioned?

Comment: The one the warning references at this location: /usr/bin/install_name_tool

Replace that one with the one from Xcode and see if it fixes your issue.